# F#: let mutable vs. ref

Tags: f#, mutable

First, I acknowledge the possibility that this question could be a duplicate; just let me know.

I'm curious what the general "best practice" is for those situations when mutability is desired. F# seems to offer two facilities for this: the `let mutable` binding, which seems to work like variables in "most" languages, and the reference cell (created with the `ref` function) that requires explicit dereferencing to use.

There are a couple of cases where one is "forced" into one or the other: .NET interop tends to use mutable with `<-`, and in workflow computations one must use `ref` with `:=`. So those cases are pretty clear-cut, but I'm curious what to do when creating my own mutable variables outside of those scenarios. What advantage does one style have over the other? (Perhaps further insight into the implementation would help.)

Thanks!

Comment: See also http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!689.entry

Comment: Note that in F# version 4, mutable can be used where you used to need a ref.  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/fsharpteam/archive/2014/11/12/announcing-a-preview-of-f-4-0-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-vs-2015.aspx

Answer (score 141, accepted):

I can only support what *gradbot* said - when I need mutation, I prefer `let mutable`.

Regarding the implementation and differences between the two - `ref` cells are essentially implemented by a very simple record that contains a mutable record field. You could write them easily yourself:

```
type ref<'T> =  // '
  { mutable value : 'T } // '

// the ref function, ! and := operators look like this:
let (!) (a:ref<_>) = a.value
let (:=) (a:ref<_>) v = a.value <- v
let ref v = { value = v }
```

A notable difference between the two approaches is that `let mutable` stores the mutable value on the stack (as a mutable variable in C#) while `ref` stores the mutable value in a field of a heap-allocated record. This may have some impact on the performance, but I don't have any numbers...

Thanks to this, mutable values that use `ref` can be aliased - meaning that you can create two values that reference the same mutable value:

```
let a = ref 5  // allocates a new record on the heap
let b = a      // b references the same record
b := 10        // modifies the value of 'a' as well!

let mutable a = 5 // mutable value on the stack
let mutable b = a // new mutable value initialized to current value of 'a'
b <- 10           // modifies the value of 'b' only!
```

Comment: Just a reminder: being on the stack or on the heap is an implementation detail and not exactly relevant to the question (but excellent answer nonetheless)

Comment: I would argue that knowing whether something incurs the overhead of heap allocation and collection or not is extremely relevant when deciding on what a best practice is.

Comment: @jackmott check out this article by Eric Lippert called [The Stack Is An Implementation Detail](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/)

Comment: @jaromey yes I understand that I fundamentally disagree completely with eric on that point.  You can't leave performance considerations aside when considering what is a 'best practice'.  It is often claimed that performance doesn't matter yet so much software is slow due to death from a thousand implementation details.

Answer (score 19):

**Related Question:** "You mentioned that local mutable values cannot be captured by a closure, so you need to use ref instead. The reason for this is that mutable values captured in the closure need to be allocated on the heap (because closure is allocated on the heap)." from [F# ref-mutable vars vs object fields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2942616/f-ref-mutable-vars-vs-object-fields)

I think `let mutable` is preferred over reference cells. I personally only use reference cells when they are required.

Most code I write doesn't use mutable variables thanks to recursion and tail calls.  If I have a group of mutable data I use a record.  For objects I use `let mutable` to make private mutable variables.  I only really use reference cells for closures, generally events.

Answer (score 13):

As described in [this MSDN Blog article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/fsharpteam/2014/11/12/announcing-a-preview-of-f-4-0-and-the-visual-f-tools-in-vs-2015/) in section **Simplified use of mutable values**, you no longer need ref cells for lambdas.
So in general you no longer need them at all.

Answer (score 5):

[This article](http://lorgonblog.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!701679AD17B6D310!689.entry) by Brian might provide an answer.

Mutables are easy to use and efficient (no wrapping), but can't be captured in lambdas. Ref cells *can* be captured, but are verbose and less efficient (? - not sure of this).

Comment: "(...) and less efficient" - probably, a wrapper type takes more memory.

Comment: This has changed, since F# 4.0 mutable can be captured in most cases and the need for ref is now much less.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to take a look at the [Mutable Data](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Mutable_Data) section in the wikibook.

For convenience, here are some relevant quotes:

> The mutable keyword is frequently used
>   with record types to create mutable
>   records
>
> Mutable variables are somewhat
>   limited: mutables are inaccessible
>   outside of the scope of the function
>   where they are defined. Specifically,
>   this means its not possible to
>   reference a mutable in a subfunction
>   of another function.
>
> Ref cells get around some of the
>   limitations of mutables. In fact, ref
>   cells are very simple data type which
>   wrap up a mutable field in a record
>   type.
>
> Since ref cells are allocated on the
>   heap, they can be shared across
>   multiple functions