# F# - passing reference cells to functions

Tags: f#

I'm just wondering if somebody can explain to me how to pass reference cells to functions that are not class members. I've been following the msdn page [msdn reference cells](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233186.aspx)

I have the following code:

```
let myint = ref 32
let mutable myint2 = 23

type addone() = 
    member t.myadd1func (x:int byref) = 
        x <- x + 1

let myadd1func (x:int byref) = 
    x <- x + 1

let adder = new addone()

adder.myadd1func myint
// myadd1func myint <---- this line does not compile

myadd1func &myint2 // <----- this line does though


printfn "%d" !myint
printfn "%d" myint2
```

My question is... what is the fundamental difference between the call I am making to the "Myadd1func" method on the class and the "myadd1func" function defined after it?

As I write this, I'm guessing that the function doesn't like having .net object references being passed to it as this might break compatibility with other IL components?? I don't mind using a mutable value, I just like to understand these things.

Thanks

Comment: You might also find this interesting.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221200/f-let-mutable-vs-ref

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is explained in the [Type-directed Conversions at Member Invocations](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc270597565) section of the F# specification.  For interoperability with other .NET components, ref cells can be passed to members taking `byref` parameters and the compiler will automatically treat it as the dereferencing of the cell's `contents` field.  However, this isn't done for let-bound functions, and you should directly use the addressof operator (`&`).  You can still use a ref cell, but you have to explicitly dereference the `contents` field yourself, so this should work in your example: `myadd1func &myint.contents`

Comment: Thanks very much for pointing me at the F# spec - I think there is other stuff in there that will help me when I come across situations like these.

Answer (score 5):

I think the `byref` type in F# should be used only for interoperability purpsoes where the existing features (as explained by kvb) are good enough.  If you want to declare a function that modifies some argument passed to it, I would just use ordinary reference cell (e.g. `int ref` type):

```
let myadd1func (x:int ref) =
  x := !x + 1 

let myint = ref 10
myadd1func myint
```

This may be slightly slower than using `byref` type (together with local `mutable` value), but I don't think it is needed very often in functional style, so it should be fine.