# F# handling values and references

Tags: .net, f#, reference

I need to understand something very important regarding F#: how it handles references and values.
I know that F# defines immutable and mutable objects and also know the reason why.

But there is one thing that I do not know: how are objects treated?

I mean, in C# everything is a pointer and when assigning to an object the reference of another one, data are the same, and we'll have two pointers pointing the same data.

So in C# if I have this:

```
Object myobj1 = new Object();
Object myobj2 = myobj1;
bool myobj1 == myobj2; // It is true
```

Well, what about f#?

```
let myvar: MyObj = new MyObj ()
let myvar2: MyObj = myvar
```

What's the situation here?
Does the assignment involves copy? or not.

And, generally speaking, what's f# approach to this topic? (I mean value vs reference).

Comment: See also (related but not duplicate): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221200/f-let-mutable-vs-ref

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When working with reference types and value types, F# behaves just like C#.

- When you have a reference type, it works with a reference to an instance in the heap.
- When you have a value type (built-in, declared in C# or declared in F# using `Struct` attribute),
  the value is copied when you assign it to another value or pass as argument.

The only notable difference is that standard F# types (discriminated unions, records, lists, arrays and tuples) have *structural equality* semantics. This means that they are compared by comparing the actual value stored in them and not by comparing references (even if they are reference types). For example, if you create two lists of tuples containing the same data you get:

```
> let l1 = [ ("Hello", 0); ("Hi", 1) ]
  let l2 = [ ("Hi", 1); ("Hello", 0) ] |> List.rev;;
(...)

> l1 = l2;;
val it : bool = true
```

You get `true` even though lists and tuples are reference types. If you compare the references however (*EDIT: Added sample inspired by kvb*):

```
> System.Object.ReferenceEquals(l1, l2);;
val it : bool = false
```

The use of *structural equality* makes sense in F# because the types are immutable - when you create two values containing the same data, they will always be the same. If they were mutable, you could change one and they wouldn't be equal anymore - that's why it makes more sense to use reference equality for mutable types.

Comment: OK thankyou... just one more thing... all built in types in f#, are they struct or not??? I mean are they value type? or not?

Comment: @Andry: In principle it doesn't matter - because they are immutable and have structural equality semantics, they would behave the same. From a practical point of view, it may matter (for performance). So, the answer is that all standard F# types are reference types. You can define value type by adding `[<Struct>]` to your object type declaration, but discriminated unions will always be reference types.

Comment: Thankyou Tomas, you're always my light when handling f#... :)

Answer (score 6):

As you can convince yourself with the following simple experiment, F#'s behavior is the same as C#'s:

```
printfn "%b" (myvar = myvar2)  // true
```

Or better yet:

```
printfn "%b" (obj.ReferenceEquals(myvar, myvar2)) // true
```

since as Tomas points out, the behavior of `(=)` can be a bit subtle.

From my perspective, there isn't really any logical alternative; what else could `myvar2` possibly contain?  There isn't any general mechanism for duplicating objects of arbitrary types, so the only behavior that makes sense is for `myvar` and `myvar2` to contain equal references.