# The mutable variable 'x' is used in an invalid way. Mutable variables cannot be captured by closures

Tags: f#

I have a couple of books that I am going by, but as I am working on my F# problems, I find some difficulties in syntax here. If anyone thinks I should not be asking these questions here and have another book recommendation on a budget, please let me know.

Here is the code that reproduces the problem I am having with my project

```
[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let mutable x = 0

    let somefuncthattakesfunc v = ignore

    let c() = 
        let y = x
        ignore


    somefuncthattakesfunc (fun () -> (x <- 1))
    Console.ReadKey()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

I am getting the following compile error

```
The mutable variable 'x' is used in an invalid way. Mutable variables cannot be captured by closures. Consider eliminating this use of mutation or using a heap-allocated mutable reference cell via 'ref' and '!'.
```

Any clue ?

Comment: Use `ref` instead of `mutable`, but you're never assigning to `x`, so why is it `mutable` anyway?

Comment: @ildjarn I am assigning to x in the lambda expression

Comment: No, you're comparing to `x` -- assignment is `<-`. ;-]

Answer (score 5):

As the error explains, you can't close over mutable variables, which you are doing in:

```
let y = x
```

and

```
(fun () -> x = 1)
```

It suggests you use a `ref` instead if you need mutation:

```
let x = ref 0

let somefuncthattakesfunc v = ignore

let c() = 
    let y = !x
    ignore

somefuncthattakesfunc (fun () -> x := 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

As the error message says, mutable variables cannot be captured by closures, use a reference cell instead:

```
let main argv = 
    let x = ref 0

    let somefuncthattakesfunc v = ignore

    let c() = 
        let y = !x
        ignore

    somefuncthattakesfunc (fun () -> x := 1)
    Console.ReadKey()
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3221200/f-let-mutable-vs-ref).

Comment: I mistakenly put = instead of <- assignment operator in lambda expression. I have corrected it.  Now this solution does not work. It says x is not mutable.